# PHP ERROR One insert is causing two rows ANDROID

Tags: php, android, mysql, request, insert-into

I have a problem with my script php 
When I click on the button "Inscrire", It's call my request INSERT, but he create two rows in my table with same data.

Here is my code php :

```
<?php
require_once('assistmysql.php');

    $id_activite = $_POST['id_activite'];
    $id_users = $_POST['id_users'];
    $etat = $_POST['etat'];

    if($etat == '1')
    {   
        $sql = "INSERT INTO inscription_activite (id_activite,id_users) VALUES ('$id_activite','$id_users')";
        $result=$con->query($sql);
        if(mysqli_query($con, $sql))
            {
                echo'info enregistrée !!!!';
            }
            else
            {
                echo'dommage..';

            }
            mysqli_close($con);
    }

    else if ($etat == '2')
    {
        $sql =  "DELETE FROM inscription_activite WHERE id_users = '$id_users' AND id_activite = '$id_activite'";
        $result=$con->query($sql);
        if(mysqli_query($con, $sql))
            {
                echo'vous etes bien desinscrit !';
            }
            else
            {
                echo'quelle tristesse..';

            }mysqli_close($con);
    }


?>
```

And here my code android :

```
public class BackgroundWorker extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {

    Context context;
    AlertDialog alertDialog;
    BackgroundWorker (Context ctx) {
        context = ctx;
    }
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String type = params[0];
        String login_url = "http://192.168.20.135/scriptphp/redirectionactivite.php";
        if(type.equals("inscrire")) {
            try {
                String etat = params [1];
                String id_user = params [2];
                String id_activite = params[3];

                URL url = new URL(login_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
                String post_data =URLEncoder.encode("etat", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(etat,"UTF-8")+"&" 
                        +URLEncoder.encode("id_users", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(id_user,"UTF-8")+"&" 
                        +URLEncoder.encode("id_activite", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(id_activite,"UTF-8");

                bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
                String result="";
                String line="";
                while((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null) {
                    result += line;
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return result;
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else if (type.equals("desinscrire"))
        {
             try {
                 String etat = params [1];
                 String id_user = params [2];
                 String id_activite = params[3];

                 URL url = new URL(login_url);
                 HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                 httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                 httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                 httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                 OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                 BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
                 String post_data =URLEncoder.encode("etat", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(etat,"UTF-8")+"&" 
                        +URLEncoder.encode("id_users", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(id_user,"UTF-8")+"&" 
                        +URLEncoder.encode("id_activite", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(id_activite,"UTF-8");

                 bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
                 bufferedWriter.flush();
                 bufferedWriter.close();
                 outputStream.close();
                 InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                 BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
                 String result="";
                 String line="";
                 while((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null) {
                     result += line;
                 }
                 bufferedReader.close();
                 inputStream.close();
                 httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                 return result;
             } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             } catch (IOException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }


        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Info status");
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        alertDialog.setMessage(result);
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your PHP code, you seem to be playing the query twice :

```
$result=$con->query($sql);
if(mysqli_query($con, $sql))
```

Either do :

```
$result = $con->query($sql);
if ($result) {
```

or :

```
if(mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
```

Comment: How could I miss that, Thanks mate